# check if column value is repeated from 24 hours before for IF statement triggered

Tags: mysql, sql

so what I'm trying is to make an IF statement that checks if column value is repeated from a range of 24 hours before, and if it is like this, then condition would trigger. So I'm looking to complete something like this for column reportLastIp:

```
if new.reportLastIp = (24h before value check condition here)
then SET new.report_balance=0 and new.referperId=0
```

How could I get this working?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: In MySQL, `if` statements only exist in the context of programming blocks.  Is this for a stored procedure, function, or trigger?  If not, can you explain what you really want to do?

Comment: this is a trigger as I say in title

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want 24 and bigger, if thats wrong then just make the 23 into 24.

```
if ADDTIME(new.reportLastIp,'24:00:00') < GETDATE()
then SET new.report_balance=0 and new.referperId=0
```

Comment: Hi, Im getting error #1582 for this: Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'DATEDIFF'

Comment: this function is sql server, my bad. putting the mysql in 1 min, there ya go

Comment: hi, but this function is checking for same value? its giving me error, I am looking for the function that checks if the same value for new.reportLastIp was already set from 24 hours before, and if there is a value that matches the new one, then it triggers the condition

Comment: ah ok, then you need to supply a value column and a timestamp. Put the missing one in your question and Ill fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I would write this as:

```
IF new.reportLastIp < dateadd(GETDATE(), -1) THEN
    SET new.report_balance = 0;
    SET new.referperId = 0;
END IF
```